# Retrieve link text from hyperlink in php

Tags: php, html, text, hyperlink

I have the following code that is echoed to a webpage once a form is sumbitted:

```
echo"<tr><td style='width:30px;'></td><td colspan='2' class='border'>{$row['SiteAddress']}</td><td colspan='2' class='border2' style='text-align:right'>Folder ID: <a href='#' id='myBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>{$row['FolderID']}</a></td>";
```

The hyperlink is used to open a carousel of images in a pop-up window and the link text that is inserted as {$row['FolderID']} is needed to concatenate the path to the images.  I've found plenty of examples how to easily get the href link but I am having difficulty getting the value of the link text.  I'm sure this is a simple thing to do for some but I'm confused.  Question: How do I get the link text value into php?

Comment: Maybe `href='{$row['FolderID']}'`

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "get the link text value _into php_". The text is already in PHP, as variable `$row['FolderID']`

Comment: if `$row['FolderID']`has a value, this value appears at the place you put your variable ... but i guess, the array value is empty

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts so far I will try to clear up what I can.  The href is created in php earlier in the code and echoed out to a results webpage when a user submits a form.  A value for $row['FolderID'], such as 13,546, is the link text so that I can concatenate a directory and do a pop-up carousel of images.

Comment: If it helps, when I use the Inspect tool in firefox and look at the output for the hyperlink the code shows: <a id="myBtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">13546</a>  Just a thought but could I insert something like name=$row['FolderID'] in the original echo statement and then somehow get the name value for it?